# Translate from sql statement to linq statment

Tags: c#-4.0

How can I translate

```
select * from employees where (emp_id=@emp or @emp is null) and (dep_id=@dep or @dep is null)
```

to a LINQ statment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C#

```
int empID = [whatever...]

var e = from e in db.Employees
        where e.emp_id == empID || e.emp_id == null
        select e;
```

I'm assuming the `@emp is null` part is a typo, and you wanted `emp_id is null`. If not, just switch it around.

I'd suggest [reading some more](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoSQL5MinuteOverview.ashx) on LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no way of doing this. The LINQ providers are designed to take code and translate to SQL statements, not the other way around.